# Jqgrid can't select certain rows

Tags: javascript, php, jqgrid

I have my grid up and working fine, but when I try to select certain rows for editing it will not select that row but will select the row one or two above or below it.

Any idea what this issue might be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had several rows that were duplicate data in my database and they were colliding I believe.